# ASP.NET Core 7.0 Web API Interacting with .NET Framework 4.7.2 Membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an established solution consisting of ASP.NET WebForms websites that are built using .NET Framework 4.7.2, these websites cannot be changed or updated. I can only access the databases the websites refer to.

I have been tasked with creating an ASP.NET Core 7.0 Web API that can perform some basic 'supporting' functionality on these websites from a single location and as part of that I have been asked to include user management. Since these websites use .NET Framework the user management is done using the Membership class which ASP.NET Core 7.0 doesn't use.

I have attempted to create a 'wrapper' project that itself targets .NET Framework 4.7.2 within the same solution as the ASP.NET Core 7.0 Web API and added a reference to the wrapper project within the API. Inside this wrapper project I have a method that calls `Membership.Provider.CreateUser()` however when attempting to step through this process I am presented with the below exception

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Reference assemblies cannot be loaded for execution. (0x80131058)
>
> Inner Exception
> BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.

Looking in the bin\Debug folder for my API I can see the `System.Web.ApplicationServices` dll is present.

I have tried:

- Restarting Visual Studio.
- A Visual Studio clean operation then rebuilding.
- Manually deleting the \bin and \obj folders of the API & Wrapper projects then rebuilding.

Example of the projects below

.NET Framework 4.7.2 Wrapper Project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Security;

    public class MembershipWrapper 
    {

        public string CreateUser(string emailAddress_, string forename_, string surname_, Guid companyGroupId_, string contactNumber_, UserStatus userStatus_, UserType userType_, Languages language_, List<string> roles_ = null, string userName_ = null)
        {
            string username = string.Empty;
            string password = GenerateRandomPassword();
            Guid userId, processId;
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName_))
            {
                username = GenerateUsername(forename_ + surname_);
            }
            else
            {
                username = userName_;
            }
            userId = Guid.NewGuid();

            //additional businesslogic & validation here

            MembershipUser user = Membership.Provider.CreateUser(userName_, password, emailAddress_, "", "", true, userId, out createStatus);

            return createStatus.ToString();
        }
    }
```

.NET Core 7.0 API Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost(Name = "PostUser")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostUser([FromBody] UserCreation userCreation_)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (CreateUser(userCreation_))
                {
                    case MembershipCreateStatus.Success:
                        return Ok();
                        break;
                    default:
                        return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex);
            }
        }

        [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
        public MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(UserCreation userCreation_)
        {
            MembershipCreateStatus membershipCreateStatus = MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError;

            try
            {
                MembershipWrapper wrapper = new MembershipWrapper();
                var result = wrapper.CreateUser(userCreation_.EmailAddress, userCreation_.Forename, userCreation_.Surname, Guid.Empty, userCreation_.ContactNumber, SupportCentre.Wrappers.Enums.UserStatus.Deleted, Wrappers.Enums.UserType.Admin,
                        SupportCentre.Wrappers.Enums.Languages.English);
                
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            { 
                
            }

            return membershipCreateStatus;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Hi @Matt Holcroft, your wrapper project is. NET Framework 4.7.2 version, right? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can't mix .NET Framework and .NET Core projects. "Wrapping" doesn't change the fact that your library targets .NET Framework  and requires the WebForms libraries that implement Membership. You don't need the Membership class to read the database though. You can query the tables directly

Comment: Keep in mind that even in .NET Framework, the Membership provider was abandoned in MVC, Web API and later. The [MVC 3 tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7) show a completely different model, similar to what is now available in Identity. You could create a MVC/Web API *Framework* project that exposes the functionality you want to the ASP.NET Core application, but frankly, those WebForms sites should have changed over 10 years ago. MVC 3 came out in 2010

Comment: There's a serious security issue too. The Membership provider came out when MD5 was considered secure. Nowadays, cracking those passwords probably takes just minutes. Forget about modern security measures like 2FA, OTPs etc.